# Javascript line break after 5 increments!

Tags: javascript, loops, break

I'm stuck.... Yet again.
I need to add a line break after every 5 increments using javaScript. For example

```
img1        img2         img3         img4        img5
img6        img7         img8         img9        img10
```

Here is what i was thinking of.

```
for (i = 0; i < blah.length; i++) {
    imgholder.innerHTML += i;
    if (i > 5) {
        imgholder.innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
}
```

Ok, I do realize it is not the most structured piece of code (so I'm sorry), but it is just a sample.
Hope it made sense. Feel free to ask more questions for clarification.
Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will break after element 6, 7, 8 (zero-based, so add 1 to get the image number) and so forth since they're *all* greater than 5. So you'll get:

```
img1   img2   img3   img4   img5   img6   img7
img8
img9
img10
```

You need to replace:

```
if (i > 5) {
```

with:

```
if ((i % 5) == 4) {
```

so that it breaks after element 4 (img5), 9 (img10), 14 (img15) and so on.

And, since you asked for an explanation, the modulo operator gives you the remainder when you do a division. So `12 % 5` can be worked out as what's left over when you divide `12` by `5`. `12 / 5` gives you `10` with a remainder of `2`, so `12 % 5` is `2`.

The following table may help:

```
  i  | i % 5
-----+------
  0  |   0
  1  |   1
  2  |   2
  3  |   3
  4  |   4 *
  5  |   0
  6  |   1
  7  |   2
  8  |   3
  9  |   4 *
 10  |   0
 11  |   1
 12  |   2
```

You can see it cycling through the values `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` so we just have to pick the value where you want to insert the breaks (after `4`, marked with `*`).

Comment: Greate explanation, thanks very much. Hope I had enough reputation to vote you up.

Answer (score 4):

This is low tech, but it will do:

```
if(i % 5 == 4) {
    imgholder.innerHTML+='<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'modulus' operator, `%` instead of greater-than `>` in your if check.

```
  for(i=0;i<blah.length;i++) {
    imgholder.innerHTML+=i;
    if(0 == ((i+1)%5)) {
      imgholder.innerHTML+='<br>';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the modulus operator

```
for(i=0;i<blah.length;i++){
  if((i+1) % 5 == 0){
    your br goes here
  }
}
```